# Google Ads targeting my already long term customers. How to fix this?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, google-ads, marketing, ad-targeting

My company provides web based services on long term (years) contract basis.

My customers would regularly visit my website to access the updates about their account.

But all my customers have noticed that my Google ads banners are showing up on most websites they visit, on top, sides and bottom.

All my customers have agreed that they have never seen my Google Ads before visiting my website and subscribing to my service, recommended by someone or from printed flyers.

Since I am targeting to make a trustworthy customer base initially, I am selling my services at rates my competitors can't match. 
So if a targeted customer is informed about my service, I am positive that they would go for it while its still on discounted rates.

So I wanted google ads to show my ads to customers who are looking at services like mine, searching with my service keywords etc.

Its a waste to show my already existing customers my company ads.

Kindly please advise on how to set this right.

Comment: What an interesting question. I only wish I knew what to tell you.

Comment: Thank you @closetnoc. Can you let me know whether you have faced a similar situation too ? Is this an expected behaviour that we see very often ? I assume google knows everything including the mails that I sent to my customers that says "Thank you for purchasing my services" to their GMAIL account and after all they purchase it through Chrome web browser. So they could surely avoid targetting my existing customers. I know repeated sales products like consumables can be marketed to already purchased customers, but marketing a car to someone who just bought the same car is just wrong !

Comment: Google puts a lot of work into optimizing for the people most likely to convert.  Top of that list: your existing customers.   Google knows the customer was already on your site because of either Google Analytics or they clicked from a Google search result.  Just as you work to make sure every visitor converts, Google works to make sure every visitor who converts arrives through a Google ad and not organic.

Comment: So if the ads are popping up then check the user agreement you might not be able to get around the advertising then againit could be the work of a hacker.

Comment: @Harper Thanks. Exactly my point, google knows who my existing customers are, and I don't want them to be targeted at all. Is there a way to tell google that my nature of business needs new customers and not the returning ones ?

Comment: @rdarw I was not referring to any popup ads that have intruded into my website. This question is related to the paid Google Ads campaign that I run    is targeting my existing users costing me views and clicks.

Comment: This reddit user noticed same issue : https://www.reddit.com/r/google/comments/3jptyp/google_ads_targeting_existing_customers/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Its a waste to show my already existing customers my company ads.

It isn't, but we won't address using remarketing to drive referrals, reviews and upsells in in this question.

To combat segmenting with remarketing, lets focus on this part of the question:

> My customers would regularly visit my website to **access the updates about their account.**

Perfect, I am going to assume there is some kind of standard URL structure in your 'account' section of your website.

Let's say it's `/account`

If there is a lack of global structure, then I would advise using a Custom Variable or firing an event like 'logged in customer' in-between two script tags on those pages or when they log-in.

If you haven't already, [integrate your Google Analytics accounts with your Google Adwords Account](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033961?hl=en).

1. In Google Analytics, create a new segment and in the *Advanced* segement, select `Conditions`.
2. For filter, set it to `Users`, `Include` and the parameter for `Page` and set it to `account` or whatever the equivalent is. Note: Another good option would be Event Action/Label etc that would fire off when a user logs in.
   [image: Here we have 70 users]
3. Name your segment, then hit save. Then, in your normal view right-click on your segment and select `Build an Audience`.
   [image: Build your Audience]
4. Choose your Adwords account and set in the values for your Audience Definition.
   [image: Create your Audience Definition]
5. Adwords time. Log in to your Adwords accounts and select your campaign.
6. (a) If it's a `Search` Campaign, select the 'Audiences' Tab.
7. (a) Scroll down to 'Campaign Exclusions` and under 'Ad Group Exclusions' select your 'Interests and Remarketing', choose 'Remarketing Lists' then select your audience.
   [image: Remarketing Lsit]
   [image: Now Excluded]
8. (b) If it is a `Display` campaign, go to the 'Display Network' Tab and under 'Add Campaign Exclusions', select `Interests and Remarketing`. Same process as 7 (a).

And there you have it, now your campaigns will exclude all visitors from your website who have been to the `accounts` section until the cookie expires.

Comment: Thanks you so much @inkovic. This is exactly what I wanted.